# BigQuery Export schema - how to export complete event column from firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I already link the firebase to bigquery, and everyday a new table gets created with the date stamp. The columns within the export can be found in the following link: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en
BUT, there is not firebase analytics data(such as add_porduct_like, add_product_to_cart, and so on) being export. how can I export complete data into BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics data is already exported in those daily tables formed each day in Big Query.

What is required over here is to run queries in order to extract the relevant data.

Take a look at this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query#querying_google_analytics_for_firebase_data_using_bigquery) for sample queries when Firebase Data is exported to Big Query.

In short, you need to make use of the schema and based on the Field Name, you can query the data obtained in Big Query by Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit an event with parameters to Firebase Analytics, it is stored as an array in the column `event_dim.params`. 
To get data from database, you will need to use this query (I'm using standard SQL):

```
SELECT 
  event_dim.name AS event_name, 
  event_dim.params AS event_params

FROM 
  `project.your_app.app_events_20171109`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) as event_dim
```

If you want to get specific parameter, you'll also have to unnest another field:

```
SELECT 
  event_dim.name AS event_name, 
  event_dim.params AS event_params

FROM 
  `project.your_app.app_events_20171109`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) as event_dim,
  UNNEST(event_dim.params) as params

WHERE params.key LIKE "add_product_to_cart"
```

You can read more about how Firebase Analytics stores data and how to use UNNEST function here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/bigquery-tip-unnest-function.html